# Why is this decomposition possible

Tags: functional-analysis

I am studying a proof in Arvesons book on spectral theory. It is something in the proof of corollary 3 [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=2ouk0d3QW4YC&lpg=PA93&ots=cPBzcX0_Xp&dq=arveson%20spectral%20theory%20atkinson&pg=PA99#v=onepage&q&f=false) that I don't understand.

On line 3: why is it possible to find $T_n$ such that $A_n = A + T_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a way of stating that $A_n \to A$, namely $A_n = A + T_n$, with $T_n = A_n-A$.